# Keybindings to simulate next tabstop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a ListBox where I'd like to "simulate" the next/previous tab key when entering a different key.

Means: If I press "Enter" I'd like to have the behaviour of "NextTab".

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{HereNextTabPlease}" />
  </ListBox.InputBindings>
</ListBox>
```

Do I have to do it over a ViewModel, which should implement a Property "NextTabCommand" and then informs the View to change the CurrentTab? Or is there anything within XAML to do so? Like:

```
 <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Window.NextTab}" />
```

I don't like to put this information into my viewmodel - it'd be such an overload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it correct, you wanted to select control when you press Enter key which does the what otherwise done achieve through tabbing. If so, I don't think there any inbuilt mechanism which does that. However, similar is achieved through attached property [here](http://madprops.org/blog/enter-to-tab-as-an-attached-property/) and all credit goes to Matt Hamilton.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! Indeed this is what I need - but not only for "Enter", also for Up and Down

Comment: I hope you can definitely work for any Key given an example of some Key(Enter). Can't you ?